# Like and And Or ISNull using Linq to Entity Entity Framework4? How do you do that?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a screen in my project " Enquiry" where I user can perform 2 kinds of search.I cannot figure out how to do a "like" or "And or is null" in Linq to entity.

1. Simple Search  ( Search in all fields  using "Like" operator)
2. Advanced Advanced Search (Use "And" Operator)

So lets take these 3 tables and make up a noddy example.

1. Customer Table  (CustomerID,Name,Surname)
2. Address(AddressID,Street,City)
3. CustomerOrder (OrderID,OrderName)

Basic search :
this is how I would do it in Sql

```
  SELECT TOP (100) C.Name,C.Surname,CA.Street,CA.City,CO.OrderName
  FROM Customer C 
  LEFT JOIN CustomerAddress CA ON C.CustomerID=CA.CustomerID
  LEFT JOIN CustomerOrders CO ON C.CustomerID=CA.CustomerID   
  WHERE  (C.CustomerID LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'  
  OR C.Surname LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' 
  OR C.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'        
  OR CA.Street LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
  OR CA.City LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
  OR  CO.OrderName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%') )
```

Advanced Search

This my sql where clause

```
    WHERE  (C.CustomerID =@CustomerID or @CustomerID ISNULL  
    AND C.Surname =@Surname or @Surname ISNULL
    AND C.Name=@Name or @Name ISNULL        
    AND CA.Street =@Street or @Street ISNULL
    AND CA.City =@City or @City ISNULL
    AND  CO.OrderName =@OrderName or @OrderName ISNULL)
    AND ((ModifiedDate BETWEEN ISNULL(convert(varchar,@FromDate,101),'01/01/1901')
    AND ISNULL(convert(varchar,@ToDate,101),'12/31/9999'))
```

How do you do Likes or and or is null in entity framework?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `LIKE`, you can use `Contains`, `StartsWith`, or `EndsWith`.  For `IS NULL`, use `== null`.

Example:

```
var list = from p in Products
           where (p.Description.Contains("v") && p.Description.StartsWith("C"))
                    || p.MFRCode == "TOYOTA"
                    || p.Universal == null                   
           select p;
```

will cause EF to generate this SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[MFRCode] AS [MFRCode], 
[Extent1].[MFRProductID] AS [MFRProductID], 
[Extent1].[Universal] AS [Universal], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (([Extent1].[Description] LIKE N'%v%') AND ([Extent1].[Description] LIKE N'C%')) OR (N'TOYOTA' = [Extent1].[MFRCode]) OR ([Extent1].[Universal] IS NULL)
```

and produce these results:

[image]

*Edit*

I used [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to generate these results.  It's a great tool, free to use (there's an option to purchase an Intellisense feature), and definitely worth a look if you'd like to experiment with different LINQ queries and see the SQL that EF is generating (it's good for general LINQ experimentation and quickly trying out simple code as well).

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.Managed to make it nearly all work.I have a problem in creating a "Like" with integer.Do I need to do something like   "SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CustomerID)).Contains("12") .but the sql output is nothing like   c.CustomerID LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'  I get WHERE (STR( CAST( [Extent2].[CustomerID] AS float)) LIKE N'%1%')

Comment: @user231465, I just tried using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`, and I get the correct results.  The sql that EF produces in this case is not as simple as what you would code by hand.  It casts to float, then to string using the `STR` function, then does the `LIKE` comparison.  For some reason, there is no overload for `StringConvert` that takes an `int`, so the `(double)c.CustomerID` is the reason for the cast to `float`.  Also, I assume `.Contains("12")` resulted in `LIKE N'%12%'` in your comment, not `LIKE N'%1%`.

Comment: is there anywhere an example how to do "AND OR SYNTAX" eg "  AND CA.City =@City or @City ISNULL " thanks

Comment: @user231465, you would just use the C# logical operators, `&&` and `||`.  See the example in my answer and the sql that was generated in the where clause.

Comment: @adrift. Thanks for your reply.but I have used the logical operators for And or but the EF did not produce the syntaxt I was expecting the "or @City is null" was missing .mmm

Comment: @user231465, when i use `where p.Description == description || description == null`, EF generates `WHERE [Extent1].[Description] = @p__linq__0 OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL`.  I'm not sure why EF generates it this way, but it's there...

Answer (score 0):

```
int? customerID = null;
string surname = "abc";

var q = from c in oc.Customers
  where (customerID == null || c.CustomerID == customerID)
    && (surname == null || c.Surname == surname)
  select c;
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply.the query above does not seem to produce a and or conditional clause eg "AND CA.City =@City or @City ISNULL ".Any ideas